# Implementing Keyboard interaction on modal pop up [Angular JS]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a custom component in angular js for a modal pop up. Everything works fine. Now I would like to implement keyboard interaction on this. That is when the Modal pop up shows the message, user should be able to close by Pressing Enter key.

```
(function () {
    "user strict";
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp");
    myApp.component("ModalDialog", {
        bindings: {
            show: '=',
            title: '=',
            type: '=',
            okCallback: '&?',
            okText: '=?',
            cancelCallback: '&?',
            cancelText: '=?'
        },
        replace: true, 
        transclude: true, 
        controller: function ($element, $attrs) {
            var $ctrl = this;
            $ctrl.dialogStyle = {};
            if ($attrs.width)
                $ctrl.dialogStyle.width = $attrs.width;
            if ($attrs.height)
                $ctrl.dialogStyle.height = $attrs.height;
            if ($attrs.okCallback)
                $ctrl.okEnabled = true;
            if ($attrs.cancelCallback)
                $ctrl.cancelEnabled = true;
            $ctrl.hideModal = function () {
                $ctrl.show = false;
            };
            $ctrl.ok = function () {
                $ctrl.okCallback();
            };
            $ctrl.cancel = function () {
               $ctrl.cancelCallback();
            }
        },
        template: '<div class="ng-modal" data-ng-show="$ctrl.show">\n' +
        '<div class="ng-modal-overlay" ng-click="$ctrl.hideModal()"></div>\n' +
        '<div class="ng-modal-dialog" ng-class="{\'warning\' : $ctrl.type.toLowerCase() === \'warning\'}" data-ng-style="$ctrl.dialogStyle">\n' +
        '<div class="ng-modal-dialog-header">{{$ctrl.title}}</div>\n' +
        '<div class="ng-modal-dialog-content" ng-transclude></div>\n' +
        '<div class="ng-modal-dialog-footer ng-button-group">\n' +
        '<button data-ng-show="$ctrl.okEnabled" class="ng-button-primary" data-ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">{{$ctrl.okText}}</button>\n' +
        '<button data-ng-show="$ctrl.cancelEnabled" class="ng-button-secondary" data-ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">{{$ctrl.cancelText}}</button>\n' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>'
    });
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-modal-dialog show='$scope.alertModal.shown' width='400px' data-title='$scope.alertModal.title' data-type="$scope.alertModal.type" ok-callback="$scope.closeAlertModal()" ok-text="$scope.alertModal.okText">
    {{$scope.alertModal.message}}
</ng-modal-dialog>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.closeAlertModal = function(){
    $scope.alertModal.shown=! $scope.alertModal.shown; 
};
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note-- the `ESC` key is a more conventional button to be pushed to clear a modal--  the `enter` key I would expect to push the "main" button (if any) in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have to "listen" to keydown event.

Something like this:

```
 windowElem.on("keydown", function (event) {

    switch (event.which){
           // escape key
           case 27:
              doStuff();               
              break;    
           //enter key
           case 13:
             doOtherStuff();
             break;                    
    }
});
```